# C# web browser history

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I'm developing a web browser in C# using Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to save the user's search history in a database and display it in a listbox. However, the database and listbox are empty. I have no idea why it's not working. 
I have a bookmark button that works in the same way. It functions fine. The bookmarks show up in the listbox. 
Any thoughts as to why the history listbox is always empty?

```
public class HistoryItem
{
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public static void AddItem(HistoryItem item)
{
    var adapter = new HistoryTableAdapter();
    adapter.Insert(item.URL, item.Title, item.Date.ToShortDateString());
}

public static List<HistoryItem> GetItems()
{
    var adapter = new HistoryTableAdapter();
    var results = new List<HistoryItem>();
    var rows = adapter.GetData();
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        var item = new HistoryItem();
        item.URL = row.URL;
        item.Title = row.Title;
        item.Date = DateTime.Parse(row.Date);
        item.Id = row.Id;
        results.Add(item);
    }
    return results;
}

private void DisplayLabel(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Done";
    toolStripProgressBar1.Value = 0;
    var item = new HistoryItem();
    item.URL = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
    item.Title = webBrowser1.DocumentTitle;
    item.Date = DateTime.Now;
    HistoryManager.AddItem(item);
}

private void HistoryManager_Load(object sender, EventArts e)
{
    var items = HistoryManager.GetItems();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        HistoryListBox.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} ({1}) [{2}]", item.Title, item.URL, item.Date));
    }
}
```

Comment: its not appear in the listbox or in the database? if its not appearing on the listbox, show us how did you fetch the data and bind the information into the listbox.

Comment: It does not appear in either.

Comment: how did you insert the data into database?

Comment: It's hard to tell what might be going on because you're missing a big chunk of the logic in the snippet above. Is `AddItem` ever called? Are you sure that the table adapter is actually hooked to a valid table?

Comment: AddItem is called in the DisplayLabel method (when the web browser document is finished loading), and the table adapter is hooked to a valid table. The code is nearly identical to my code for adding/displaying bookmarks, which works fine. I have recreated the browser(in a new solution) 3 times, only to find the same issue every time. I can't figure out what I'm missing. Could it have something to do with getting the date? That is the main difference between my bookmarks and history code.